# trigger 'This video can't be embedded.' facebook video

Tags: javascript, facebook, video

I try to trigger an facebook video error in javascript , I have this error in the player ( 'Unavailable
This video can't be embedded.' )

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.5'
  });
  // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
  var my_video_player;
  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
    if(msg.type === 'video') {
      my_video_player = msg.instance;
    }
  });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if(d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>



<div  
class="fb-video" 
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/businessinsider/videos/10153852489789071/" 
data-width="500" 
data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
```

How can I trigger when a video can't be play ?

Comment: Are you just asking how you can _test_ this case? Well set a video you have control over to not embeddable via the Facebook UI.

Comment: I just want to know if I can play the video or not

Comment: Do the SDK events work here? If so, inspect the my_video_player object, maybe it contains the info whether the video could be played or not in some form.

Answer (score 0):

In your facebook app dashboard, go to App review and make it public.

[image: Screenshot]